# Find the derivative of a piecewise function using the limit definition

Tags: python, sympy, derivative

So I create a piecewise function like this:

```
x= sp.symbols('x')
f = sp.Piecewise(
        (1, x==0),
        (sp.sin(x)*(x+1)/x, True))
```

but if i substitude `x` with `0` I'll get `nan`:

```
f.subs(x,0)
nan
```

So 1st question is why `==` doesn't work well with `sympy.Piecewise`? 
Well, I change it to that:

```
f = sp.Piecewise(
        (sp.sin(x)*(x+1)/x, sp.And(x < 0, x > 0)),
        (1, True))
```

And it works kinda.

Next thing I'd like to do is to calculate a derivative of the function using it's definition in `x = 0`: I need to calculate a limit:

[image]

 So I far as I need to calculate it in `x = 0`, I code this:

```
Δx = sp.symbols('Δx')
expr = f.subs(x, Δx)/Δx
sp.limit(expr, Δx, 0)
```

But it outputs `oo` which means infinity. And that's kinda not true, cuz if I call `diff` function, I'll gain `0`, which is kinda true(at `x = 0` the derivative of `f` is `0`):

```
sp.diff(f, x).subs(x,0)
0
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong with my code and how can I correct it. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Equality `==` is structural equality, not mathematical equality. It evaluates to True or False at once, there is no "wait until we know the value of x". The object `Symbol('x')` and the object `Integer(0)` are not equal structurally, hence `Symbol('x') == Integer(0)` is False. See [SymPy gotchas](https://docs.sympy.org/latest/gotchas.html#double-equals-signs). What you meant is the relation `Eq(x, 0)` which represents the equality relation that is not evaluated to a boolean until we know more about `x`. So, use

```
f = sp.Piecewise(
    (1, sp.Eq(x, 0)),
    (sp.sin(x)*(x+1)/x, True))
```

Second, the definition of derivative (at 0) is the limit of `(f(Δx) - f(0))/Δx`, and you didn't subtract `f(0)`

```
expr = (f.subs(x, Δx) - f.subs(x, 0))/Δx
sp.limit(expr, Δx, 0)
```

results in 1, which is actually correct. (The derivative is 1, not 0).

Incidentally,

```
>>> sp.diff(f, x).subs(x, 0)
0
```

is wrong because SymPy (like other CAS) is not very good in calculus with piecewise functions.

Comment: Oh, thank you a lot, I really messed up with derivative definition and `==` equality.